# Azure Function Timer Trigger is running when I open function in portal and (RunOnStartup = false)

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, timer-trigger

I am facing this problem:
I created Azure Function in Python which will trigger on 12th hour of every day. But the problem is that whenever I open this function in portal.azure.com my function triggers and execute (regardless of scheduled time). I have added this in my function.json file but still facing this problem:

```
{
"scriptFile": "__init__.py",
"bindings": 
[{
"name": "mytimer",
"type": "timerTrigger",
"direction": "in",
"schedule": "0 1 13 * * *",
"RunOnStartup": false,
}]}
```

Comment: Show the function invocation logs if the function is running regardless of specified timer trigger schedule.

Comment: Check the Schedule value once: https://i.imgur.com/Ktny0mZ.png - For Triggering every 12 hours and https://i.imgur.com/883IQBi.png - For Trigger at 12 on every day

Answer (score 0):

What does the logs say when you start the function? Usually the logs prints the next 5 runs for the fucntion.

`0 1 13 * * *` should be at the first minute past 1pm how about `0 0 2/12 * * *` `2/12` is every 12th hour between 2am and 11pm

`{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day of the week}`

As far as i read the [cheat sheet here](https://arminreiter.com/2017/02/azure-functions-time-trigger-cron-cheat-sheet/), it could be why it runs every second

Comment: `* 1 13 * * *` => `Every second, at 1 minutes past the hour, between 01:00 PM and 01:59 PM`?

Comment: @jikuja yes you are right - my answer would trigger that... My fault. Updated the answer